# AspectJ - @Around Skipping execution but run other advice

Tags: annotations, aspectj

I have run into issues where after @Around skips the method execution and returns a value right away, it also skips rest of Aspect advices. See my example code:

```
public class MyService {
    ...
    @AnnotationAround
    @AnnotationAfterReturning
    public MyResult get() {
       ...
    }
...
}

@Aspect
public class AroundInjector {
   @Pointcut(value="execution(* *(..))")
   public void anyPublicMethod() {
   }

   @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(around)")
   public Object aroundThis(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, AnnotationRound around) throws Throwable {
       return new MyResult();
   }
}

@Aspect
public class AfterReturningInjector {
   @Pointcut(value="execution(* *(..))")
   public void anyPublicMethod() {
   }

   @AfterReturning(pointcut="@annotation(afterReturn)", returning="result")
   public void permissionCheckOwnership(JoinPoint jp, AnnotationAfterReturning afterReturn, Object result) throws Throwable {
       System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>> never here");
   }
}
```

So, after @Around advice returns directly, the @AfterReturning is never executed. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your method never returns anything because its execution is prevented by the around advice, so the advice for its return joinpoint is not executed.

To solve this either call the method inside your around advice (and take care to have the correct aspect [precedence](https://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/01/01/advanced-aspectj-part-iv-declaring-aspects-precedence/)), or make its content part of the around advice.

Comment: I agree. The original poster should not be surprised that a method execution which *never* occurs does not trigger any `after` advice. This is like wondering why someone never leaves a house she has never entered...